# Find out path of program

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

On Unix I can call certain programs from everywhere, like `sort`, `pwd` or `my_custom_script.sh`.

How can I find out, where on the system `my_custom_script.sh` really resides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `type command`. `which command` only look in the PATH so can be misleading for builtins (like pwd), functions and aliases.

Comment: `which` actually also lists aliases.

Comment: I'm afraid it can't. `which` isn't a shell builtin so has no idea about internal commands/aliases and the like.

Comment: On my Linux box, "which" is unexpectedly aliased. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

Use `which`

```
which sort
```

Gives you (for example):

```
/usr/bin/sort
```

This also helps you to troubleshoot issues with your PATH, e.g. if you have several versions of the same binary installed and you don't know which one is called.

So if you have multiple versions, you can use the `-a` switch:

```
charon:~ werner$ which -a ruby
/Users/werner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
/Users/werner/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: `which` will work for my_custom_script.sh but will give misleading information about pwd and similar commands.